# Why did Ilúvatar scold Aulë for creating Dwarves?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

When Aulë attempted to make his own creation, the Dwarves, Ilúvatar seemed to not like this and questioned Aulë for doing so.

Was it because Ilúvatar decreed Elves were supposed to be the first of his creations to awake in he lands of Middle Earth?

Comment: Because he’s not the Messiah, he’s a very naughty... no hang on, wrong franchise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Because Aulë tried to create rational life.**

In Tolkien's (I will remind you, intensely Catholic) morality, attempting to usurp Ilúvatar's authority, or bypass his Plan, is a Bad Thing. The published *Silmarillion* isn't clear on this, but Tolkien writes it more clearly in the unsent Letter 212 (emphasis Tolkien's):

> Aulë *[...]*, one of the Great, in a sense 'fell'; for he so desired to see the Children, that he became impatient and tried to anticipate the will of the Creator. Being the greatest of all craftsmen he tried to *make* children according to his imperfect knowledge of their kind. When he had made thirteen, God spoke to him in anger, but not without pity
>
> *[...]*
>
> The One rebuked Aulë, saying that he had tried to usurp the Creator's power; but he could not give independent *life* to his makings. He had only one life, his own derived from the One, and could at most only distribute it. 'Behold' said the One: 'these creatures of thine have only thy will, and thy movement. Though you have devised a language for them, they can only report to thee thine own thought. This is a mockery of me.'
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 212: To Rhona Beare (unsent). October 1958</sup>

We can contrast this with Yavanna, who, though desiring creatures of her own, asked for permission *before* creating them, and had a very different experience from the process:

> So I see in my thought. Would that the trees might speak on behalf of all things that have roots, and punish those that wrong them!
>
> *[...]*
>
> Then Manwë sat silent, and the thought of Yavanna that she had put into his heart grew and unfolded; and it was beheld by Ilúvatar. Then it seemed to Manwë that the Song rose once more about him, and he heeded now many things therein that though he had heard them he had not heeded before. And at last the Vision was renewed, but it was not now remote, for he was himself within it, and yet he saw that all was upheld by the hand of Ilúvatar; and the hand entered in, and from it came forth many wonders that had until then been hidden from him in the hearts of the Ainur.
>
> Then Manwë awoke, and he went down to Yavanna upon Ezellohar, and he sat beside her beneath the Two Trees. And Manwë said: 'O Kementári, Eru hath spoken, saying: "Do then any of the Valar suppose that I did not hear all the Song, even the least sound of the least voice? Behold! When the Children awake, then the thought of Yavanna will awake also, and it will summon spirits from afar, and they will go among the [animals] and the [plants], and some will dwell therein, and be held in reverence, and their just anger shall be feared.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 2: "Of Aulë and Yavanna"</sup>

Unlike Yavanna, Aulë acts almost Melkorian, independently trying to create something as great as the Children of Ilúvatar.

Comment: As usual Jason, you hit the nail on the head (no pun intended). It's interesting to note that Melkor searched for the "Flame Imperishable", which is the giver of life, the power of creation. He obviously failed, because the fire probably resides within Eru himself. This sets the background for the story of the Dwarves and gives reason behind why Aule could not "animate" them later on. Eru receives the secret flame, and no one else. Edit: As regards your edit, yes it was a test, to see if Aule would go the way of Melkor and create his own discord.

Comment: Do Dwarves have the least of existences, of the three races then? 
They do not have the immortality of the Elf or the "Gift" of Man

Comment: @user001 [They're certainly different](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82860/), but I don't know that I'd say that makes them "least." They were made according to their nature, as with Elves and Men

Comment: @JasonBaker Not that they themselves are least but that they would seem to have nothing other than the one life

Comment: @user001 [Unless you're Durin](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86560). Maybe

Comment: @JasonBaker Actually, from the link you gave.  "For they say that Aule cares for them and gathers them in Mandos in halls set apart for them, and there they wait, not in idleness but in the practice of crafts and the learning of yet deeper lore. And Aule, they say, declared to their Fathers of old that Iluvatar had accepted from him the work of his desire, and that Iluvatar will hallow them and give them a place among the Children in the End. Then their part shall be to serve Aule and to aid him in the re-making of Arda after the Last Battle."

Comment: Did the Dwarves spontaneously come to life as Aulë raised his hammer, or at that instant did Ilúvatar give them life?

Comment: @RobertF The second one. Very next paragraph starts: "But Ilúvatar spoke again and said: 'Even as I gave being to the thoughts of the Ainur at the beginning of the World, so now I have taken up thy desire and given to it a place therein; but in no other way will I amend thy handiwork, and as thou hast made it, so shall it be."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it's been a while since I've read *The Silmarillion*. Now I'm curious if, aside from Aulë's Dwarves and Yavanna's Ents, any other Valar created their own race?

Comment: @RobertF Manwë probably made the Eagles, although it's not clear from the published *Silmarillion*. If this is made more explicit in other writings, I can't recall it off-hand

Comment: @JasonBaker, note that the Eagles and the Ents are both cases of shaping existing life, rather than creating it anew.

Comment: @Mark [Arguable](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53957/31051)

Comment: This is a good answer but not a great answer.  He is scolded, but in good Catholic fashion, he repents.  Remember this is Tolkien trying to cast Christianity in a Pagan framework.  

It is the Act of Contrition that frees Aulë's work from any taint of rebellion and sin.  Through an act of grace Ilúvatar forgives him and adopts the creation as his own.

Comment: @nick Always good to get a kick in the pants every so often. Better now? I'm not much familiar with Catholic teachings, but I found a letter from Tolkien that discusses the issue much better

Comment: @JasonBaker, for the reasons I state.  He is scolding.  This is an Act of Contrition.  Everything else works though.